# How to read a Text File from Firebase to Android App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, kotlin, firebase-storage

I am working on content based Android App.I used Firebase to Upload all Text files (in rtf or doc files).After I uploaded one text file to Firebase, I created a detailed activity that downloads the file from the firebase but the text files are not read, it shows nothing.Here is my Kotlin Code...

```
class detailOne : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var mTextView : TextView? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.detailone)

        val myButton = findViewById(R.id.butOne) as Button
        mTextView = findViewById(R.id.myText) as TextView

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
        val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
        val storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://yehwot-eta.appspot.com/story.rtf")


        try {
            val localFile = File.createTempFile("text", "rtf")
                storageRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener {

                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    print("Connection is Lost!Please Try Again")
                }
            }
        } catch(e : IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        myButton.setOnClickListener {
            val myIntent = Intent()
            myIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            myIntent.type = "text/plain"               
            myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"This is my Text")
            startActivity(myIntent)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load file to firebase storage.  Here is code that allows a tab delimited text file to be "downloaded" and used by a Kotlin android app fragment within a recycler view:

```
    // get the file from firebase
    val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
    var storageRef = storage.reference
    val seriesRef = storageRef.child("YourFileName.txt")

    val localFile = File.createTempFile("YourFileName", "txt")

    seriesRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener {
        // Local temp file has been created
        activity?.let { fragmentActivity ->
            try {
                val lines: List<String> = localFile.readLines()
                localFile.delete()

                lines.forEach { seriesString ->
                    // check for header row
                    if (seriesString.contains(kSeriesHeaderString, true)) {
                        // do nothing for the header string
                    } else {
                        // set the image id
                        val series =
                            Series(
                                seriesString
                            )

                        series.imageId = resources.getIdentifier(
                            series.logoImageName.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT), "drawable",
                            fragmentActivity.packageName
                        )

                        SeriesList.addSeries(series)
                    }
                }

                // get all series and set the series list
                seriesList = SeriesList.getAllSeries()
                seriesListRecyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "-------------------------------------------------------")
                Log.e(TAG, "ERROR: failed to read series file, stacktrace to follow.")
                Log.e(TAG, "-------------------------------------------------------")
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read $kStarWarsSeriesFileName: ${it.message}")
        Toast.makeText(view?.context, "Failed to read $kStarWarsSeriesFileName:: ${it.message}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

This code gets the firebase instance for the app and gets the reference to the file.  My file is in the root of Firebase storage.

The File is saved in local storage.

The file is read line by line skipping the header record if a header exists.

After getting the lines, the localFile is deleted as I no longer need to keep the file.  In my case, the file needs to be retrieved each time the app is loaded.

Each line from the file is used to create the necessary "series" instance

Then all the series instances are returned

Try/Catch and exception handling are managed as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer! In order to use a text file,I shouldn't have to load into Firebase Storage.Instead I upload directly to Firebase Database in Json format.