# Download Files from Firebase Storage and read data

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download from my Firebase Storage so I can read the data on it. I can't find any examples online on how to do this, all examples involve images. The files will either be .csv or .txt files.

I've been reading this documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files but I don't know what to do after implementing any of the functions, such as the "Download in memory" example.

Ideally this data (integers/doubles) will be placed in an array to be plotted on a chart.

Any ideas on how this could be done? This is being written in Kotlin.

*Update*

I currently have the code:

private fun downloadFile(fileName: String, uID: String?) {

```
        val fileRef = Firebase.storage.reference.child("$uID/$fileName.txt")


     val localFile = File.createTempFile("Data", ".txt")

     fileRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener {
        println("File Downloaded")

         activity?.let{

             try{
                 val lines: List<String> = localFile.readLines()
                 localFile.delete()



             }catch (e: Exception){
                 println("Error when loading file")

             }

         }

     }.addOnFailureListener {
         val toast = Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.failedToast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
         toast.show()
     }

}
```

Which is based off of the answer I found in another post: [How to read a Text File from Firebase to Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350532/how-to-read-a-text-file-from-firebase-to-android-app).
This is working great but now there is a problem now is that I need to convert the lines List to an array of type 'Any' but the function .toTypedArray() is returning the pointer of the list and not the values.

```
                 val dataArray: Array<Any> = lines.toTypedArray()
```

Comment: After downloading the data from Firebase the problem should be isolated from Firebase. Did you try anything yet after downloading the file the way that is shown in the documentation? If not, it's unlikely we can help better than the documentation. or a search for "parsing CVS file in Android" already does.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Forgive me if I get confused with any of the documentation, I am a novice at Android coding. So far what I have setup is a Firebase project and mobile application which are connected. I know that this is done correctly because I am able to list all of the user files in Firebase Storage on the mobile application. To download I have added all of the "Download in memory" code in a button click which would take an inputted file name and follow the path to download that file. I guess my biggest question is the documentation says the data is returned but how can I see that data?

Comment: You could log it to see it. But instead of describing your code further in comments, I recommend editing your question to show the [minimal complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That is really by far the most effective way to get help with code-related problems here on Stack Overflow.